# NextJS Webworker `window is not defined`

Tags: node.js, webpack, web-worker, next.js

Getting a window not defined error when using NextJS and `next-web-worker` package.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withWorkers = require('@zeit/next-workers');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

const webpackConfig = (config) => {
  config.plugins = config.plugins || [];
  config.target = 'universal';
  config.output = {
    ...config.output,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    globalObject: '(this || global)',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000'
  };

  config.plugins = [
    ...config.plugins,

    // Read the .env file
    new Dotenv({
      path: path.join(__dirname, '.env'),
      systemvars: true
    })
  ];

  return config;
};

module.exports = withPlugins([[withCSS], [withWorkers]], webpackConfig);
```

The recommended work around appears to be setting the globalObject to this or global But that isn't working. Are there any other work arounds for this?

Answer (score 1):

I was just experiencing this same error and it was solved by following [the advice here](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/337#issuecomment-439688991):

```
yarn add @zeit/next-workers@canary
```